# Can anyone help me setting up the Salesforce Mobile SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile, sdk, salesforce

I'm having a horrible time getting this thing to work at all. I've spent two days reading the documentation on Salesforce's website, the example code in the distributed SDK and just generally beating my head against the wall.

The most frustrating part is that I think I'm just missing the login screen, but I can't find anything that will tell me how to make one. From what I can tell, it's just a UIWebView that points to the SF login page.

Here's what I've been able to figure out so far:

1. Added the SDK to my project (SalesforceSDK, SalesforceOAuth, RestKit) and linked against all the libraries that are mentioned in the [Git readme](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/blob/master/readme.md#using-the-native-rest-sdk-in-an-existing-project).
2. Included `"SFRestAPI.h"` in my server communications class I'm using to send and receive data from the server.
3. Called the SFRestRequest using the code from the XCode template that's distributed with the SDK:

   ```
   SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:@"SELECT Name FROM User LIMIT 10"];
   [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
   ```
4. Added the delegate methods:

`#pragma mark - Salesforce REST API delegate methods`

```
- (void)request:(SFRestRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(id)jsonResponse
{
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonResponse);
}

- (void)request:(SFRestRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

- (void)requestDidCancelLoad:(SFRestRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"%@", request);
}

- (void)requestDidTimeout:(SFRestRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"%@", request);
}
```

5. Saw this in the console:

```
`2012-09-11 10:23:44.128 ClientApp[39697:c07] SFRestAPI::send: <SFRestRequest 0xd4a9cb0 
endpoint: /services/data 
method: GET 
path: /v23.0/query 
queryParams: {
  "q" : "SELECT Name FROM User LIMIT 10"
}`
```

None of the delegate methods for SFRestRequest were called.

Here's what hasn't worked:

#### Making my app delegate a subclass of SFNativeRestAppDelegate

This created about 12 duplicate symbol errors:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SFNativeRestAppDelegate in:
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClientApp-bpccblcllzkzvudxtwutuqliagld/Build/Intermediates/ClientApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClientApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Documents/Out to Lunch/ iOS Apps/ClientApp/ClientApp/dependencies/SalesforceSDK/libSalesforceSDK.a(SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SFNativeRestAppDelegate._authViewController in:
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClientApp-bpccblcllzkzvudxtwutuqliagld/Build/Intermediates/ClientApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClientApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Documents/Out to Lunch/ iOS Apps/ClientApp/ClientApp/dependencies/SalesforceSDK/libSalesforceSDK.a(SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SFNativeRestAppDelegate._viewController in:
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClientApp-bpccblcllzkzvudxtwutuqliagld/Build/Intermediates/ClientApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClientApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Documents/Out to Lunch/ iOS Apps/ClientApp/ClientApp/dependencies/SalesforceSDK/libSalesforceSDK.a(SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SFNativeRestAppDelegate._window in:
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClientApp-bpccblcllzkzvudxtwutuqliagld/Build/Intermediates/ClientApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClientApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Documents/Out to Lunch/ iOS Apps/ClientApp/ClientApp/dependencies/SalesforceSDK/libSalesforceSDK.a(SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SFNativeRestAppDelegate in:
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClientApp-bpccblcllzkzvudxtwutuqliagld/Build/Intermediates/ClientApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClientApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Documents/Out to Lunch/ iOS Apps/ClientApp/ClientApp/dependencies/SalesforceSDK/libSalesforceSDK.a(SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol _kDefaultLoginHost in:
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClientApp-bpccblcllzkzvudxtwutuqliagld/Build/Intermediates/ClientApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClientApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SFNativeRestAppDelegate.o
    /Volumes/Wallace/Users/gromitt/Documents/Out to Lunch/ iOS Apps/ClientApp/ClientApp/dependencies/SalesforceSDK/libSalesforceSDK.a(SFAccountManager.o)
ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is more than a little embarrassing, but I don't want people to keep trying to answer this problem so here goes:

I had two copies of SFNativeAppDelegate.h added to my app. I was looking through the files included in the SF Mobile SDK, and I must have skipped over it. So I added it a second time, and that's when my problems started.

I have it working now. Here's what I did:

1. Create a Native app using the SalesForce project template.
2. Go to your Native app's directory in the Finder. Copy the `dependencies` directory into your *existing* project.
3. Open the Native project in XCode and copy over the Settings.bundle to your existing project. Grab the `SFAuthorizingViewController.xib` while you're in there, too. Close the Native project. You don't need it anymore.
4. Open your existing app's plist file. Add a key named `SFDCOAuthLoginHost`, and set it to either test.salesforce.com or login.salesforce.com
5. In your existing app delegate, include `SFNativeAppDelegate.h`, `SFOAuthCoordinator.h` and 
   `SFOAuthCredentials.h`
6. Change the interface declaration line from this:

   ```
   @interface YourAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
   ```

   ...to this:

   ```
   @interface YourAppDelegate : SFNativeRestAppDelegate
   ```
7. Add two properties to YourAppDelegate:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, readonly) SFOAuthCoordinator *coordinator;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) SFAuthorizingViewController *authViewController;
   ```
8. Go to YouAppDelegate.m. Add the following lines:

   ```
   // Fill these in when creating a new Remote Access client on Force.com
   static NSString *const RemoteAccessConsumerKey = @"...yourConsumerKeyGoesHere...";
   static NSString *const OAuthRedirectURI = @"https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success";
   ```
9. Add these methods as well (the Authorizing Coordinator was the secret sauce I was missing)

   ```
     #pragma mark - Salesforce.com login helpers

       - (NSString*)remoteAccessConsumerKey {
           return RemoteAccessConsumerKey;
       }

       - (NSString*)oauthRedirectURI {
           return OAuthRedirectURI;
       }

       -(NSString *)oauthLoginDomain {
           return @"test.salesforce.com";
       }

       -(void)login{
          [self.coordinator authenticate];
       }

       - (void)logout {
           [self.coordinator revokeAuthentication];
           [self.coordinator authenticate];
       }

       - (void)loggedIn {
           //provide the Rest API with a reference to the coordinator we used for login
           [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] setCoordinator:self.coordinator];
           //[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] setApiVersion:@"24.0"];
       }

       - (UIViewController*)newRootViewController {
           NSLog(@"You must override this method in your subclass");
           [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:@selector(newRootViewController)];
           return nil;
       }

       - (SFOAuthCoordinator*)coordinator {
           //create a new coordinator if we don't already have one
           if (nil == _coordinator) {

               NSString *appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];
               NSString *loginDomain = [self oauthLoginDomain];
               NSString *accountIdentifier = [self userAccountIdentifier];
               //here we use the login domain as part of the identifier
               //to distinguish between eg  sandbox and production credentials
               NSString *fullKeychainIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",appName,accountIdentifier,loginDomain];


               SFOAuthCredentials *creds = [[SFOAuthCredentials alloc]
                                            initWithIdentifier:fullKeychainIdentifier
                                            clientId: [self remoteAccessConsumerKey] encrypted:NO ];


               creds.domain = loginDomain;
               creds.redirectUri = [self oauthRedirectURI];

               SFOAuthCoordinator *coord = [[SFOAuthCoordinator alloc] initWithCredentials:creds];
               coord.scopes = [[self class] oauthScopes];

               coord.delegate = self;
               _coordinator = coord;
           }

           return _coordinator;
       }
   ```

*Now* you're ready to make a call using the SFRestAPI. If the user hasn't already logged in, the SalesForce authentication page will appear the first time you try to use it.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help. Again, super-embarrassed.

Answer (score 3):

Targets-> build Settings —> other Linker Flags

As specified in the Rest Kit Tutorial we changed added a flag called `-ObjC-all_load` now edit that to just display `-ObjC` and then the application works like a charm.

Hope this helps those people who are facing this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the `SFNativeRestAppDelegate` issues, as ultimately, you want to inherit from that class, so that you can get authentication "for free".

Assuming you don't actually define SFNativeRestAppDelegate somewhere in your developed app, it looks like you may have build state issues that are causing the conflicts you're seeing.  When I see duplicate symbols issues between a referenced static library and random symbols down in the DerivedData folder, I usually take the following actions:

1. Close out Xcode.
2. Blow away DerivedData entirely (`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*` — This is temporary build data, and will be regenerated with your next Xcode build).
3. Optionally, blow away the Xcode project state data for my app (`rm -rf MyProjectDir/MyProjectDir.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/ MyProjectDir/MyProjectDir.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/`), just to make sure my project state is clean.

When you're able to inherit from SFNativeRestAppDelegate, all of the authentication linkage should happen behind the scenes, including setting up `[SFRestAPI sharedInstance]` with the credentials it needs to make authenticated calls to the service.  It looks like not being able to inherit from SFNativeRestAppDelegate is the crux of your problem.  Once that's done, the pattern you've described for REST API access looks correct.

If you have further follow-up questions, you can also consult with the folks on [the Mobile board](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Mobile/bd-p/mobile) at developerforce.com.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't remove the errors. I closed XCode and emptied out the DerivedData in both places you've recommended. I also removed the app from the simulator to get a fresh install. No joy.

Answer (score 0):

Did u set the class with the SFRestAPI delegate??

@interface GSK_SFADataSyncManager : NSObject **< SFRestDelegate >**

```
SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:query];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
```

Try clearing your search path from the Build settings... do u have any other lib along with this??